# Unity inconsistent camera rotation with mouse

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So far learning unity, camera rotation with mouse is the thing that has given me the most problems. Now the problem I am facing is, when making a first person controller based on rigidbody, that the rotation of the character and camera with the mouse is inconsistent and jittery.

This [youtube video](https://youtu.be/Cu97YI13AHY), shows the problem. In it, i am smoothly moving the mouse but the rotation seems to sometimes skip some intermediate rotations and jump to new values.

This is the hierarchy I am currently using for the character as well as the attached components:
[image: Image showing the hierarchy and attached components of a rigidbody based character]

And this is the complete code for the script

```cs
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;

    [RequireComponent(typeof(Rigidbody), typeof(Collider))]
    public class CompleteRBController : MonoBehaviour
    {
    [Header("Referenced components:")]
    [SerializeField]
    private Rigidbody _rb;
    [SerializeField]
    private Transform _cameraTransform;


    [Header("Mouse Settings")]
    public float _mouseSensitivity = 100f;
    [SerializeField]
    private float pitch = 0f;
    [SerializeField]
    private bool _mouseInverted = false;


    [Header("Parameters:")]
    [SerializeField]
    private float _speed = 10f;
    [SerializeField]
    private float _sprintSpeed = 15f;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        //Get input mouse
        float mouseX = Input.GetAxisRaw("Mouse X") * _mouseSensitivity * Time.fixedDeltaTime;
        float mouseY = Input.GetAxisRaw("Mouse Y") * _mouseSensitivity * Time.fixedDeltaTime;

        //Get input keyboard
        float vertical = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
        float horizontal = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");

        // Debug.Log(string.Format("Vertical: {0}, Horizontal: {1}", vertical, horizontal));

        bool isSprinting = Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift);

        //Rotate
        pitch += (_mouseInverted) ? -mouseY : mouseY;
        pitch = Mathf.Clamp(pitch, -89, 89);

        _cameraTransform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(pitch, 0, 0);
        transform.Rotate(transform.up * mouseX);

        //Move
        Vector3 move = (transform.forward * vertical + transform.right * horizontal).normalized * ((isSprinting)? _sprintSpeed : _speed);
        _rb.velocity = new Vector3(move.x, _rb.velocity.y, move.z);
    }

}
```

I will also add a list of things I tried to change to make it smooth:

- Changing getAxisRaw with getAxis. No effect on the smoothness of the camera movement.
- Lerping the vertical rotation. Adds too much delay, does not really seem suitable for FPS controller? How would I lerp the yaw?
- Move the rotation from FixedUpdate to Update. Does not do anything, and we are editing a rigidbody so it would be still better to do it on fixedUpdate with all other physic related calculations.
- Make separate components one for the rotation and the other for the movement. does not help either.

Sometimes on the first seconds of the simulation i does work smoothly but after a little while it becomes wonky again.

I dont really know how to fix it / what is causing the problem. I would really appreciate it if you could help me with this or put me in the right track to understanding the problem.

Thanks in advance for helping me.

Comment: Try putting the camera movement in `LateUpdate()`. I am not sure the results with your given code as I do not know how the entire project is setup, but this might help. The other thing is all input code should be in `Update()` not `FixedUpdate()`. Only use physics calculations for `FixedUpdate()`. I would store your input as variables in `Update()`, update your movement in `FixedUpdate()` and update the camera in `LateUpdate()`.

Comment: @TEEBQNE thanks for the advice! it really lowered the jittery effect and added a better order for the script execution, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The skipping occurs whenever the FixedUpdate does not match the updating of a frame / Update(). Thats why you should put all Input related stuff in Update and all Physics related stuff in FixedUpdate. I would recommend you to make a Inputmanager Method and a CalculateMovement method. Then put the Inputmanager Method in Update and the CalculateMovement method in FixedUpdate.  Also Time.fixedDeltaTime is not the same as Time.DeltaTime. **If you put the Input in Update instead of FixedUpdate, you have to change it to Time.DeltaTime instead.** Hope i could help you! :)

Comment: Thank you for explaining why the effect is happening, changing the stuff the way you say with the changes from @TEEBQNE solved the problem.